# Trying to use jquery hasClass to break hover functionality

Tags: jquery, html, class, jquery-selectors, traversal

I am trying to break a function if a certain condition is met (that an element has a class, this class is added and subtracted dynamically)

Code:

```
this.buildMainToolsBar = function(options,display){

    var all =                       options.all || null,                                                        
        $mainToolsBarRef =          $('#mainToolsBar'),                                                         
        $disabledTools =            $('#mainToolFill, #mainToolStrokeStyle, #mainToolStrokeColour');

    if($disabledTools.hasClass('toolDisabled1')) {

        return;

    }else{

        $('form [id^=mainTool] > .toolInfo, form [id^=mainTool] > .navDown',$mainToolsBarRef).hover(function(){     

            $(this).parents('div[id^=mainTool]:not([id=mainToolsBar]):first').addClass('toolHover');            

        },function(){

            $(this).parents('div[id^=mainTool]:not([id=mainToolsBar]):first').removeClass('toolHover');

        });

    }
```

The class toolDisabled1 only appears when clicking on a particular element. The problem seems to be that the condition is returning true even before toolDisabled1 has been found.

Instead of:

```
return;
```

I also tried:

```
$disabledTools.removeClass('toolHover');
```

To try and break the function.

I also tried

```
('$disabledTools[class=toolDisabled1]').removeClass('toolHover');
```

How do I dynamically detect that the toolDisabled1 class has been added and therefore return out of the function?

Hope this is clear if you need more code let me know.

Comment: You have some pretty complex selectors. We're going to need some markup to validate your selectors. Also, a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be VERY helpful.

Comment: If you mean the  $('form [id^=mainTool] > etc. all of that is working, that was built by a javascript developer before me. The entire js file currently runs at nearly 10,000 lines of code. So something much simpler would be needed for jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lay in that the variable `$disabledTools` is selecting multiple elements. If any one of the elements within this jQuery selection has the class of `toolDisabled1` then your if statement will return true.

Is the class `toolsDisabled1` applied to any one of these elements (`$('#mainToolFill, #mainToolStrokeStyle, #mainToolStrokeColour')`) when you do your check?

Comment: Yes, basically when the client drags a particular element onto the canvas, all 3 of these will have toolsDisabled1 class added. I think long term I could store differing options in there if needed.

I am polishing off a drawing tool which renders svg. Of course once this is working I can apply it to a multitude of tools (radius, opacity etc).

Comment: ok just to confirm the problem then. 

When you do this check:-

`if($disabledTools.hasClass('toolDisabled1'))`

the class of `toolDisabled1` is not applied to any of the elements in `$disabledTools` and so should not return true? If that's the problem, then the above check is occurring after that class is being added to your element. If that check occured anytime after that class exists on one the `$disabledTools` elements then it would return false. 

Look at your  code to see when that class is applied to any of those elements and then look to see when the above check occurs.

Comment: Ha, I can't post a reply here as I dont have enough characters.

Comment: OK, I will try and paraphrase as best I can. 2 elements on the canvas. Client clicks a rectangle #mainToolFill: <div id="mainToolFill" class="toolColorSelect toolTyp1 toolActive"> Client selects what we call an iso element (fill stroke not allowed). #mainToolFill is now: <div id="mainToolFill" class="toolColorSelect toolTyp1 toolDisabled1"> If the client clicks anywhere else on the canvas or back on the rect the toolDisabled1 class is removed. The toolHover class is added dynamically on hover and it is this that I cannot break.

Comment: To my mind if anything in $disableTools currently has the class toolDisabled1 then the hover function should be broken for that element? Or would it break for all other elements too?

Comment: (I think I understand what you are saying about when the check occurs).

Comment: your check will return true (i.e. `return;`) on all elements if anything in `$disabledTools` currently has the class `toolDisabled1`.

Comment: when is `buildMainToolsBar`  ran?
Rather than doing a check on a class, I think you would be better to look into the .on and .off events in jQuery, and everytime the toolsDisabled1 class is added you simply instead turn off the hover event. And when the toolsDiabled1 class is removed you can simply set your hover events up again.

Comment: Um, OK I will look into that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could look into setting up your hover events using the .on method. Then where you would normally add the `toolDisabled1` class (on selection of what you call an iso element) you could turn off your hover events. Then when necessary (on click anywhere else on the canvas or back on the rectangle) you can re setup your hover events.

I have written a small example of this technique here: http://jsfiddle.net/XyDUV/

Comment: Thank you for this, at present the only drawback with the project is that we are using jquery 1.6.1 we may be able to upgrade to 1.7, so I would need to use bind events until we upgrade. But I will see if I can implement something similar with your code, thanks again.